# How to specify the text size of a vertex index in a 3D mesh using Labeled

Tags: text, mesh, properties

My code takes a list of `{x, y, z}` vertices and displays a convex hull with each vertex labeled by its index in the list.  Here is a minimal working example of the problem,

```
pts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {4, 3}];
chull = ConvexHullMesh[pts];
HighlightMesh[chull, Labeled[0, "Index"]]
```

[image]

However, the size of the vertex labels is tiny and I have been unable to find any method to make the text larger. Labeling the axes etc. and changing the text there is straightforward. Does anyone have an idea how to do specify the size of the vertex text. Same issue if I want the edges labeled or the faces of the triangles. I am showing a simple icosahedron.

Comment: You should include some sample data so we can try out your code. That said, have you tried using the `LabelStyle` option e.g. `Labeled[0,"Index",LabelStyle->Directive[FontSize->20]]`?

Comment: @N.J.Evans, I can't seem to find any way of changing the fontsize. Any application of `LabelStyle` like you suggested makes the labels vanish.  And using `FullForm` I don't see any occurrences of `Graphics3D[Text[...]]` to use a replacement rule on.

Answer (score 4):

This was difficult to find, but I think this is how you do it, using `MeshCellLabel` and `MeshCellMarker`

```
ConvexHullMesh[pts,
 MeshCellLabel -> {0 -> "Marker"},
 MeshCellMarker -> 
  Table[{0, n} -> Style[n, 25], {n, 1, 4}]]
```

[image]

Or you can use `HighlightMesh` if you've already created the `ConvexHullMesh` as below.  You can apply any `Style` elements,

```
HighlightMesh[chull, Labeled[0, "Marker"],
 MeshCellMarker ->
  Table[{0, n} -> 
    Style[n, 25, Hue[n/4], 
     FontFamily -> "Comic Sans MS"], {n, 1, 4}]]
```

[image]

I don't see how to use `Labeled` to label different cell specs, but you can use `MeshCellLabel` in this way,

```
ConvexHullMesh[pts,
  MeshCellLabel -> {0 -> "Marker", 1 -> "Marker", 2 -> "Marker"},
  MeshCellMarker -> Join[
      Table[{0, n} -> 
          Style[n, 25, Red, 
            FontFamily -> "Comic Sans MS"], {n, 1, 4}],
      Table[{1, n} -> 
          Style[n, 35, Blue, 
            FontFamily -> "Courier"], {n, 1, 6}],
      Table[{2, n} -> Style[n, 35, Purple, 
            FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"], {n, 1, 4}]
      ]]
```

[image]